# Regex - match emails in filenames, return list of email addresses

Tags: regex, windows, email, grep, cygwin

I have a directory of text files like so:

```
listedname_ _email@domain.com__subject_date.eml
```

The filenames are guaranteed to have this pattern during the "email" portion:

```
email@domain.xxx_
```

So, email, at-sign, domain, period, tld, underscore. *(They will not always have a leading underscore, due to not everyone setting their "name" in their email client.)*

There are ~1,000 files in a directory on Windows, though I have Cygwin tools installed and can navigate to the directory. The file contents also have a line in it guaranteed to look like this:

```
From: "Bob Lawblog" <boblawblog@domain.law>
```

What I want to do is use grep or whatever tool to return a list of email addresses and nothing more, in this format:

```
email@domain.com <line break>
email2@domain.com <line break>
email3@domain.com <line break>
```

No leading or trailing underscores, no email bodies, no subjects, etc. *(Getting it in a comma-separated list would be awesome too, but not necessary.)*

Can someone help me with the regex/grep command for it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have understood your question. Correct me if I'm wrong. It seems you have two options to 'get' the email addresses:

1. Use the file name, and apply regex.
2. Use the `From:` line in each file to get the desired email addresses.

I like the second option the most, as finding regex to match an email address from: `listedname_ _email@domain.com__subject_date.eml` will be tricky, because what if the email address contains multiple underscores?

To get a list of email addresses from within each file, try this:

```
awk '/^From:/ { print substr($NF,2,length($NF)-2) }' *.txt > outfile
```

If you'd prefer a csv of these email addresses, use `printf`:

```
awk '/^From:/ { printf "%s,", substr($NF,2,length($NF)-2) } END { printf "\n" }' *.txt > outfile
```

Comment: This worked almost perfectly! Changes I had to make: *.txt to *.eml, and when it wrote to CSV (used that option), I opened it in Excel and transposed them using Copy -> Paste Special (check Transpose) in a new worksheet so I could import a row-based CSV into my email client. Thanks a ton!